# Extracting a Part of a Hex-encoded String

Tags: python, string, hex, pyserial

Given the string: `aa0a051c1400`, how would I go about extracting just `05` or the `1c`? I'm reading serial responses and I need to examine fragments of hex data to decipher what how much data is coming down the pipe after this initial data packet.

Comment: What's the pattern? I think you would use a regex for this. `import re`

Comment: Do you always want to find '05' and '1c' or is the its position in the string the significance? It's really not clear what you want.

Comment: is your input data the ascii string "aa0a051c1400", or binary string "\xaa\x0a\x05\x1c\x14\x00"

Comment: @LarryBattle - If its looking for static strings, regex is not needed.

Comment: I think I answered my own question... sometimes this happens. Still, input is highly encouraged and rewarded with pats on the back.

to keep to the example above, to capture '05' in the above hex encoded string simply count the number of characters that need to be trimmed off of each end to get to the important stuff. For '05 (the 5th and 6th characters):

>>> string = 'aa0a051c1400'
>>> part1 = string[4:-6]
>>> part1
'05'

Comment: You could also use `string[4:6]`, which also gets the 5th and 6th character, without being dependent on the length of the string.

Comment: I am both inputing a binary and then reading an ascii string. The question involved reading the ascii string. I figured out how to snip off the part I needed. I have to write some logic that decides how many packets of data will follow this serial response (example: aa0a051c1400). So I just needed know was values came in specific positions, not specific values.

Comment: Great. thanks folks! I'm still new to python. Most of my experience is with MATLAB and shell scripts so I'm trying to get into a 'real' language now and I've got to clear the 'learning curve'.

Answer (score 1):

Just parsing the string by index works fine. If you want to parse by character index:

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

def get_hex(stream, idx):
    return hexlify(unhexlify(stream)[idx])

get_hex('aa0a051c1400', 0)
'aa'
```